# Issues with neural surrogate using Flux

Tags: julia

I am trying to build a *neural surrogate* using **Flux.jl**, the goal is to develop a function which is comparable to `kriging` function in estimating interpolated values.
The code is shown below:

```
using Plots
using Surrogates
using Flux

f(x) = sin(x)
x = range(0, 10.0, length = 9)
x= Float32.(x)
y = f.(x);
scatter(x,y)
model1 = Chain(
  Dense(1, 5, σ),
  Dense(5,2,σ),
  Dense(2, 1)
)
neural = NeuralSurrogate(x, y, model = model1, n_echos = 5);

#surrogate_optimize(schaffer, SRBF(), lower_bound, upper_bound, neura, SobolSample(), maxiters=20, num_new_samples=10)
x_test = range(0, 10.0, length = 101)
x_test= Float32.(x_test)

res = [neural(i) for i in x_test]

plot!(x_test, result)
```

However, I am getting a method error, as following:

```
MethodError: no method matching NeuralSurrogate(::Array{Float32,1}, ::Array{Float32,1}; model=Chain(Dense(1, 5, σ), Dense(5, 2, σ), Dense(2, 1)), n_echos=5)
```

May I know what is the cause of this error? And how may i resolve this issue?

Comment: The Goal here is to replicate the functionality of https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html using `neural` networks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NeuralSurrogate` constructor requires a lower and upper bound. The examples in the Surrogates.jl docs show this but if you're unsure you can always use the `methods` function.

```
julia> methods(NeuralSurrogate)
2 methods for type constructor:

    (::Type{NeuralSurrogate})(x, y, lb, ub; model, loss, opt, n_echos) in Surrogates at /srv/julia/pkg/packages/Surrogates/3CmhS/src/NeuralSurrogate.jl:24
    (::Type{NeuralSurrogate})(x::X, y::Y, model::M, loss::L, opt::O, ps::P, n_echos::N, lb::A, ub::U) where {X, Y, M, L, O, P, N, A, U} in Surrogates at /srv/julia/pkg/packages/Surrogates/3CmhS/src/NeuralSurrogate.jl:4
```

A working example:

```
using Plots
using Surrogates
using Flux

lb = 0.0
ub = 10.0
f(x) = sin(x)
x = range(lb, ub, length = 9)
x= Float32.(x)
y = f.(x);
scatter(x,y)
model1 = Chain(
  Dense(1, 5, σ),
  Dense(5,2,σ),
  Dense(2, 1)
)
neural = NeuralSurrogate(x, y, lb, ub, model = model1, n_echos = 5);

x_test = range(lb, ub, length = 101)
x_test= Float32.(x_test)

res = [neural(i) for i in x_test]

plot!(x_test, res)
```

Comment: Have you worked on this? I am having some issues with the output, it seems the `result` does not map the whole function `f(x)`. I am guessing it is because of the kind of output values I am getting from the `flux function -> neural()`. Any idea, how may I make it to map the function `f(x)` through interpolating?

Comment: When I run this for a high number of epochs (like 10000) I get what I would expect a smooth curve that interpolates between the points in the training data. 5 epochs is not enough for convergence. Beyond the domain of the training data, all bets are off of course. Are you dissatisfied with the result?

Comment: thanks, yeah you are right, after increasing the number of epochs it is trying to fit better. I have also added an additional `optimization function` (taken from the documentation) and now the predicted results are fabulous!

Amazing suggestion, highly appreciated!